# What are some best practices for translating internal server error messages to client readable messages in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

Lets say I have couple of modules that handle authentication, One for each authentication provider (Google, Facebook, Email etc).

I also have a router that uses these modules to authenticate users request.

Lets say now that one of the users tries to authenticate and one of the auth module sees that the token is expired. I create an error inside that module with an internal message *"token expired"* or something like that, then pass it back to the calling router module. The router wants to send back a client readable message like *"Your session has expired, please try to log out and in again"*.

So the problem is **where to translate the error messages from their internal representation to their client readable versions.**

There are two options the way I see it:

1. Do it inside each of the auth modules since they know best what was the problem. Downside - breaks the module abstraction, the module now has to deal with clients messages.
2. Do it in the router. Downside - need to create error codes / names and use an error handler with long list of *case* arguments to map each internal error to the client error. Might need to handle specific auth module errors as well, for example in email authentication the activation link in the email can be expired and the action needed is different then Facebook expired token.

What are some best practices to solve this problem, are there any Node / Express modules that help in some way ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be to use Express middleware for error handling.

```
function (err, req, res, next) {
   // error translation and response sending
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use a `lang` folder where the index file exposes specific language message files.

Suppose for English eng.js should be like:

```
module.exports = {
    VALIDATION_ERROR_IN: 'Validation error in',
    NOTHING_UPDATED: 'Nothing Updated',
    UPDATE_NON_EXISTING_DOCUMENT_FAILED: 'can\'t update a non-existing document',
    ID_REQUIRED: '\'_id\'is required',
    USERID_REQUIRED: '\'userId\'is required'
}
```

and index.js should be like:

```
module.exports = require('./eng');
```

if you need any other language you can create new files like eng.js where the object keys remain the same but the values are language specific.

Catch the server errors and use this as follows:

```
var message=require('message') // suppose the folder name is 'message'
    //....    
res.send(message.FIELD_REQUIRED);
```

Comment: My question wasn't about "translating" in the language kind of way but more mapping from internal messages to client side messages